# Module '"*.css"' has no exported member 'CompaniesLogo'. Did you mean to use 'import CompaniesLogo from "*.css"' instead?

Tags: css, reactjs

this may code.

```
import { CompaniesLogo,navigation,NavLinkGroup } from "./Navigation.module.css";
```

How can I import the needed classes from css into React  ?

Comment: Can you add the css file to the question?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way how you need to use as suggested by @qaismakani.

But if you want to component specific styles you can try [react-jss](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

In your **Navigation.module.css** file:

```
    .CompaniesLogo {
         // styles here
    }

    .navigation-btn {
         // more styles here
    }

    .NavLinkGroup {
         // even more styles here
    }
```

Note: we are applying styles in react using CSS modules

then use this styles in your **.tsx/.jsx**  files like below:

```
    // Don't import like this
    import { styles } from "./Navigation.module.css";

    // import like this
    import styles from "./Navigation.module.css";

    function NavigationItem(props: any) {
      return (
        <>
          <img alt="company logo" className={styles.CompaniesLogo} />
          <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" className={styles.NavLinkGroup} />
          <button className={styles["navigation-btn"]}>Submit</button>
       </>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to explicitly import individual css classes. Import your css file like this:

import "./Navigation.module.css";

and then just start using your css classes.

Comment: as far as I know, such an imper works for the whole project

Comment: This answer fails to take into account what modular CSS is about. The whole point of it is to avoid polluting the global `class` namespace.

Answer (score -2):

In your `Navigation.module.css` file you'll have class styling normally (I assume) like this:

```
.CompaniesLogo {
     // styles here
}
.navigation {
     // more styles here
}
. NavLinkGroup {
     // even more styles here
}
```

At the top of your react component file you'll import the css file like @qaismakani mentioned:

```
import "./Navigation.module.css";
```

Then, you'll use that css file just like you would in normal HTML, but instead of the `class` attribute you'll use `className` instead:

```
<div className="navigation">This is a navigation Div</div>
```